# C++ rounding to FE_TONEAREST

Tags: c++, c++11, rounding-error, rounding

Can anyone, please, explain why rounding `0.5` to `FE_TONEAREST` is giving `0`? Shouldn't it give `1 as result? Is there a way to "fix" this?

```
#include <fenv.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main() {
    fesetround(FE_TONEAREST);
    std::cout << "Rounding 0.5 to nearest = " << std::rint(0.5) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Runnable code on coliru: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9c179ca56f251628

Comment: This is only a suggestion. But maybe it is smth with floor and ceiling?  **UPDATE**: yep yes it is [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cfenv/fesetround/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`FE_TONEAREST` causes `std::rint` to round halfway cases (`±n.5`) to the nearest **even** integer value. `0` is even.

If you were to instead use `std::round` with this mode, halfway cases round "up" (away from zero), and this would result in `1`.

See [documentation for `std::rint`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/rint).

*Why* you might want this unusual form of rounding is [explained over on Mathematica.SE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2116/59830). (so your data doesn't all get shifted in one direction).

As an aside, C++ provides properly wrapped version of standard headers, with names added to the `std` namespace (although that hardly matters here): it is usual to `#include <cfenv>` rather than `#include <fenv.h>`.

Comment: A nice explanation why rounding to **even** integer is necessary for [unbiased results](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2116/why-round-to-even-integers)

Comment: Thanks, I'll add that to the answer.